# The Many Memes of Anime.SE and its Merry Fellows

Tags: discussion

> *In the style of [The Memes of Arqade and its Chat](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2187/the-memes-of-arqade-and-its-chat)* which is...
>
> > *In the style of [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)*

Memes, memes, memes - where would the internet be without them? Much like a disease, they infest everywhere and spread really fast. And like any branch of that aforementioned net, we folks in the <strike>best SE site out there</strike> A&M community are no exception in having our own offerings.

[At the behest of our <s>Overlord</s> ʞɹɐzǝɹ,](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22983274#22983274) this brilliant meta post has been born as a testament to our combined capacity for inside jokes and humor through repetition.

So, post below all the memes you can gather that originated on our site, so everyone out there can look in and see just what wonders we've achieved over the last few years.

Answer (score 20):

**Meme:** I am a tomato

**Background:** I am a tomato [(sauce)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=20002559#20002559)

**Usage:** "Toshinou Kyouko is a tomato"

[image]

Additionally, from September 27, 2015, "Tomato" became the official catchphrase of this year's Holiday Gift Exchange:

> 9. In celebration of our site graduation and our new fellow [moderator](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1530/toshinou-kyouko) (mostly the latter), "Tomato" will be a featured catchphrase for this Exchange. Use it however you prefer, as a password, greeting and farewell (like "ciao"), etc.
>
> <sub>[Come one, come all to the SECOND Annual Anime.SE Holiday Gift Exchange!](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2617/come-one-come-all-to-the-second-annual-anime-se-holiday-gift-exchange#2617)</sub>

[Confirmation that tomatoes were the best was given by the highly intelligent AI life system in chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24464071#24464071)

As tomatoes do not make many noises, sound effects to do with this meme generally take the form of squishing noises. *squish* *squish*

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ added  :)

Answer (score 19):

## Meme: Death Note Puzzles.

**Originator:** [@Eric](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=22947894#22947894)

**Cultural Height:** When the next Death Note Question is asked.

**Background:** in the anime *Death Note* the titular item and those who own one follow a set of [56 Rules](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note). For some reason people ask questions on how to kill certain people in certain ways or certain situations of use that were never in the anime.

- [Killing Conjoined Twins using Death Note](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21874/killing-conjoined-twins-using-death-note)
- [Can Death Note misfire if a person changes their name and appearance to that of another person?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21873/can-death-note-misfire-if-a-person-changes-their-name-and-appearance-to-that-of)
- [What happens if a person can't die of a heart attack?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14564/what-happens-if-a-person-cant-die-of-a-heart-attack)

All queries for using the Death Note go towards the effort for [killing Kyubey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xdUv.jpg)

**Related:** [image: You die]

Comment: Eating death note will give you digestion issues.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Is it safe to say it 'kills' your digestion?

Answer (score 17):

## Meme: Eric hates hats.

**Originator:** [Eric](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/274/%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A2)

**Cultural Height:** Every Winterbash

**Background:** Come Winterbash every year Eric does not hide his hatred for them. He [really,](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=19065388#19065388) [really,](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=18246329#18246329) [really,](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=19078013#19078013) [really,](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=19043279#19043279) [really,](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=19063905#19063905) [really,](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22971609#22971609)  hates them.

Answer (score 16):

## Our manga series, turned 4koma creation spree.

Here they are (as links, so they don't clutter the post):

1. [Taisho, The Begining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo3Am.png), by [Darjeeling](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2869).
2. [Taisho: The Taishoning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37DIG.png), by [Hakase](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/191)
3. [Krazer's Day Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIPDB.jpg), by [Darjeeling](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2869).
4. [Hakase's New Invention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylSWZ.jpg), by [Toshinou Kyouko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1530/toshinou-kyouko).
5. [Second Best Girl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QpMN.jpg), by [Darjeeling](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2869). Related: [Monthly Avatar Switchup](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2685/2869). Currently on hiatus.
6. [The Most Powerfull Shinobi Off the Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXUho.png), by [Darjeeling](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2869).
7. [Memor-X's Trap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKKrb.jpg), by [Darjeeling](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2869). Related: [Memor-X Yuri Master](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2495/2869)

Comment: Re: the fifth comic, I had just recently gotten an answer from Toshinou-san for my maid question, only to discover that Toshinou-san had become Kanbaru-san. Shocking.

Answer (score 16):

## Meme: [Memor-X Yuri Master](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%23yuri&Room=6697&User=96987&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=relevance)

**Originator:** [Memor-X](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1587/memor-x)

**Cultural Height:** Unknown

**Background:** [Happy yuri image star, he will star any yuri picture he can find](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=22954911#22954911) and [he has many levels of yuri classification](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19409823#19409823). And by the way, he's been thinking about this meme for [long ago](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=21443688#21443688)

Answer (score 12):

## Meme: Lolis are the best.

**Originator:** Nobody

**Perpetrator:** Everyone, including [Bots](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=13594160#13594160)

**Background:** It's a simple fact of life. [You heard it here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=9086110#9086110) first, [lolis are the best.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=10252167#10252167) Even [HoiHoi-san agrees.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=13594160#13594160)

Answer (score 10):

## Wider

**Originator:** Unknown

**Cultural Height:** Ongoing

**Background:** on occasion when one [posts fanart](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19313425#19313425) from [madoka-magica](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/madoka-magica) or [hidamari-sketch](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hidamari-sketch), if it does not follow the same art style used in either series one may receive a reply saying [*"wider"*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19313514#19313514).

Even characters outside the 2 series are not excluded. This is [Saber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfG75.jpg) from [fate-stay-night](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-stay-night) and [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19313720#19313720) is fanart of her using the same "wide" art style used in Hidamari....even that wasn't wide enough so it was [edited](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19313874#19313874) but [some people wanted it wider still!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19313877#19313877)

Hidamari Sketch itself may not be wide enough despite spanning [Multiple Monitors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VDhz.jpg)

Answer (score 10):

**Meme:** Jon Lin

**Originator:** [Jon Lin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/91/jon-lin)

**Cultural Height:** Ongoing

**Background:** Jon Lin is:

- The one who ranks second among users with the highest reputation scores on Anime & Manga Stack Exchange.
- The one who watches [too much anime](http://myanimelist.net/animelist/Ornette).
- <strike>The one (and only one) who has the [silver badge](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/badges/97/identification-request) for the [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) tag since February 13, 2015.</strike>

  - since identification requests were [purged](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3839/1587) he is now one of 3 who will have the [unobtainable bronze badge](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/badges/88/identification-request)
- The go-to guy for questions about [neon-genesis-evangelion](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neon-genesis-evangelion).

**Usage:** ["You post after Jon Lin answers."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=19606223#19606223)

Comment: Sounds like [Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19499/305386)

Comment: It's a Japanese name. Jon is the family name. They are siblings. :-D

Answer (score 9):

## [@Mysticial](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/17/mysticial) day.

You may be wondering ["what is @Mysticial day?"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20675851#20675851) Well, [it's @Mysticial day](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=19461221#19461221), what more is there to say? [@Mysticial](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=19461093#19461093)

Answer (score 8):

## Is Sakamoto a bot?

**Originator:** [Sakamoto](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-179/sakamoto)

**Background:**
Sakamoto is the feed for [Maid Cafe](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697), posting new questions posted on the main site...at least that's what we thought initally.

there has been times when Sakamoto has taken que from [Taisho](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2362/1587) and [posts](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=27954986#27954986) [images](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=28362968#28362968). he has also expressed his stance on [Identification Requests](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29014578#29014578). is Sakamoto really just a Feed Bot? has Taisho influenced his sentience?

Answer (score 7):

## Meme: Hakase hates puns.

**Originator:** [Hakase](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/191/hakase)

**Cultural Height:** Unknown

**Background:** [Not as much as Eric hates hats,](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22966011#22966011) but [still pretty badly.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22965858#22965858)

**Related:** [Eric Hates Hats](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2475/1587)

Answer (score 7):

## Global warming is [@Frosteeze's](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/293/frosteeze) fault.

[IT JUST IS, ALRIGHT](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=22129702#22129702)

Answer (score 7):

### Meme: ʞɹɐzǝɹ is the big bad mean boss

**Cultural Height:** Unknown

**Background:** ["@ʞɹɐzǝɹ is the big bad mean boss"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=26300787#26300787) -Tyhja

Comment: I swear I didn't make this up

Answer (score 7):

## The [@Darjeeling](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2869/darjeeling) Dippers.

**Originator**: [@Tyhja](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/123398/tyhja)

**Culprits**: [@Tyhja](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/123398/tyhja), [@Cold-Fire](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/212615/cold-fire), [@Tomato](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/74083)<sup>[[1](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2503/1458)]</sup>,[dimitri-mx](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1458/dimitri-mx)

**Cultural Height**: Unknown

**Background**: For ages people have liked a good Darjeeling thee, however here at A&M they like to take it a step further, up to the Japanese weird scale standards. Leading to our [@Darjeeling](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2869/darjeeling) being dipped in about everything you can imagine.

**Mentionable Dips**:

- ([Hot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=25649764#25649764)/[Luke-warm](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=32548604#32548604)/[Magic](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=37230974#37230974)/[Black](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=37243834#37243834)/[Salt](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=38238777#38238777)/[Fresh](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=37910005#37910005)/[Java-Island](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=36827164#36827164)/[Cold](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=36381537#36381537)) [Water](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=36359336#36359336)
- [Zimbawe money purchased](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=36912075#36912075), [Green](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=37562469#37562469)/[Red](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=35165085#35165085) [Thee](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=35018958#35018958)
- [A Birthday Cake](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=36617208#36617208)
- [The Sea](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=37194254#37194254)
- [Lava](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=37300138#37300138)
- [The Rain](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=38265193#38265193)
- [A Lake](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=38070343#38070343)
- [MX d3ullist's home](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=40368821#40368821)
- [Ectomorphing ranma mess](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40392379#40392379)

But never forget, it's
[just a dip](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=37623210#37623210)