# Why can't questions be set as Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion

When you answer a question, there's a little box in the bottom corner of the markdown box where you can select for it to be a 'Community Wiki' answer. This makes the post more readily editable by lowering rep boundaries and so on, to give the community a larger say in what the answer says.

So why can't we do this with questions too? Just like with answers, there are definitely times when this option would be beneficial.

Questions obviously *can* be wikied as evident in [this post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/385/revisions) and [this post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2474/the-many-memes-of-anime-se-and-its-user-people?cb=1), but having looked through the [privileges](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), this doesn't seem to be something that can be earned through rep. I understand a non-moderator user being unable to wiki another users post no matter their rep, but I don't understand the inability to check that box on your own posts.

Why is this feature left to moderators alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original point of a community wiki post is to encourage editing by members who do not have editing privileges. Most of the punch this feature packed was lost when suggested edits came into play.

Community Wiki answers are a lot more common than questions. So the option was removed to prevent confusion (Note that once you community-wiki a post, you can't undo). So to make a question into a community wiki, you can flag the question for moderator's attention, explain that you want the question to be community wiki and tell us why. A moderator will apply the wiki status for you.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's easy to forget that things like suggested edits weren't always around, so thanks for clearing that up.