# A&M Gift Exchange: Let's Start Conspiring!

Tags: discussion, events, tomato

[Since the sign ups have now ended](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2617/come-one-come-all-to-the-second-annual-anime-se-holiday-gift-exchange), let's start talking about the details of Conspiracy Santa.

[image: Merry Conspiracy]

First up is the format. Very soon, everyone that signed up with be getting an email from our Conspiracy Santa bot. The bot only generates the first set of emails, the rest of the work is up to the conspirators.

In total, there are 10 conspiracies with 9 conspirators each. Take your time and discuss gift ideas with one another. Everyone has until **Wednesday, October 28th** to agree on something. Be aware that if you are the Gifter, you should have gift ready to ship by **Wednesday, November 4th**, so your gift should arrive by the Christmas holiday.

If you find that you don't like the format of the emails, you can request a private Stack Exchange chat room be made for conspiracy planning.

Following the conspiracy email will be another email detailing to the Gifters who they are matched with and how to contact them to get their preferences and shipping information.

If you have any question, comments, or concerns regarding this event in particular, you can contact the moderations at **anime.se.giftexchange@gmail.com**.

Let's look forward to each other's conspiracies.

Tomato