# Anime.SE's Event Calendar

Tags: support, community-events, events

The purpose of this Meta post is to list all the events that we, the Anime.SE Community run throughout.

`-----------------------------------<Suggested Template>-----------------------------------`

```
**Event Name:** [Name of the event]

**Run time:** [When the event will run. Either a single date or when it repeated]

**Status:** [Whether or not we are still doing the event]

**Description:** [Short description about the event. Post relevant links here]
```

Answer (score 7):

**Event Name:** *Anime Club Event*

**Run time:** *TBC*

**Status:** *On-going*

**Description:** Using [Rabb.it](http://rabb.it/Krazer) and official sources such as Amazon Prime video, Netflix, Crunchyroll, and Funimation, where available [ʞɹɐzǝɹ ♦](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/63/%CA%9E%C9%B9%C9%90z%C7%9D%C9%B9) will announce in the [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) as well as our LINE group (give you LINE ID in chat for an invite)

- [Anime Club Event: Come watch anime with us this weekend!](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2666/anime-club-event-come-watch-anime-with-us-this-weekend)
- [Weekend Extra: Come watch Digimon Tri 1-4 with us!](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2676/weekend-extra-come-watch-digimon-tri-1-4-with-us)

Answer (score 7):

**Event Name:** Conspiracy Santa

**Run time:** Every Year (Starting October 10th for signups)

**Status:** On-Going

**Description:** Starting in 2014 the Anime.SE Community have started a Secret Santa kind of event for Christmas. to participate one needs ***200 reputation excluding the association bonus*** (at least 300 with the association bonus) and have an ***account age of at least 1 month*** by the end of the first day after signup

- [2015 Signup](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2617/come-one-come-all-to-the-second-annual-anime-se-holiday-gift-exchange)
- [2015 Event Start](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2650/am-gift-exchange-lets-start-conspiring)
- [2015 Gifts Showcase](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/am-gift-exchange-show-off-your-gifts)

Answer (score 6):

**Event Name:** EU A&M Meetup

**Run time:** 10th to 12th June 2016.

**Status:** Once-Off

Description: The A&M members who live in the EU are going to meet up and have fun at Anime Con 2016! Come along if you can.

**[A&M EU Meetup Report!](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3849/am-eu-meetup-report)**

[A&M EU Meetup - The convention approaches!](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/am-eu-meetup-the-convention-approaches)

[European A&M Gathering: What should we do there?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2626/european-am-gathering-what-should-we-do-there?cb=1)

[European A&M Gathering - Helpful Travel Tips & Resources (Tickets, Accommodation, etc.)](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/european-am-gathering-helpful-travel-tips-resources-tickets-accommodation?lq=1)

Answer (score 5):

**Event Name:** *Monthly Avatar Switchup*

**Run time:** *15th of every Month*

**Status:** *On-going*

**Description:** Every month on the 15th [Hakase](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/191/hakase) will announce in the [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) a theme for the next month for people to change their avatars (and in rare chances names aswell).

eg.

- [Second Favorite girl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QpMN.jpg)
- [Everyone](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24818223#24818223) [becomes](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24818422#24818422) a [Tomato](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2503/1587)

Comment: I don't like the name changes because it gets hard to keep track of who is who.

Comment: name change is rarely happen (only happen twice so far), we usually only change our avatar