# Let's make some games!

Tags: discussion

We (me and a vague but definitely real group of users) in the [Maid Café](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) would like to make some games. If you are interested, ping me in chat or post/comment here.

There are **no limitations**, but consider these things:

- It should be fun. Pretty sure nobody here likes text-based "Choose your own adventure" genre, Match-3 or Pinball. Ask yourself if you would have fun making and then playing something;
- If we want to make a game sooner rather than later, the core game should be short and simple to make;
- If we want to make a game at all, 2D is the faster route than 3D.

Use answers for game propositions. If you have some other ideas, [let's discuss them in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-).

---

#### Whatever you have in mind, don't hesitate to post it!

I'm just explaining *my personal* concerns about starting a collaborative project which often die soon because the goals are too high for project members. Compare the amount of artwork and story writing needed for an average VN and an average arcade game, and you'll see what I mean. But if suddenly a very dedicated group of people appears that want and will make a VN, I'd only be happy for them.

Part of the gig is learning how to use C#, Unity and whatnot for game development.

Comment: would we be looking to make money out of the game?

Comment: Two questions: a) Is the game necessarily going to be anime-themed in some way? b) What's the tech stack? I imagine that will limit some people; for instance, I've never written a line of C# and don't particularly want to learn it, so anything that uses Unity or .Net in general is out for me.

Comment: No theme requirements, I'm just giving examples of what is in my opinion a viable project. You can do whatever you want, if you think you can. Use whatever programming language and game engines. I will probably be using Unity and C#. I know C# and will be able to explain most language features to others, if anyone will be interested.

Comment: Making money is not the goal, but if we suddenly come up with something very good (which I doubt coz how many of us are that good at making games?) we could discuss that, why not. Basically, the goal is to have fun, to make some game, and to learn in the process about making games, programming and other gamedev related knowledge.

Comment: I like pinball... :(

Comment: If it turns out to be unity I would also be able/willing to help out :)

Comment: I'm really curious why someone downvoted this.

Comment: Most of the Links are broken [Check out this Town Management game idea](https://docs.google.com/document/d/15PziVVGKNBEUKhJo_lKGAvVcuVSXtR60DZSzndSYypk/edit?usp=sharing), [playable basic mechanics prototype](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8efZIZWps9BcWEwS05QT2F2cmc), and [these rules](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1O38jiuas7keFNQ15sF5j4xVAMBIv02lhIcQuj_rXLIw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko I like Metroid Pinball from DS, and Sonic Pinball in Sega Genesis :)

Answer (score 6):

This was an idea for a game i thought up while playing Minecraft and tried to duplicate with mods but couldn't get close. the idea is that you would find a town and set yourself up with a job there whether that be starting a farm to supply their food or working, a guard to protect it or a smith/builder.

with these jobs you have different levels of responsibility ie.

- with the farmer you with just harvest the crops or own the farm itself and handle all the fiances including hiring other farm hands
- with a guard you can just follow your orders or be the town commander and order where your guards patrol

and later if you don't want to be tied down in a single town you can go out and explore or even take up the job as a [Ronin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C5%8Dnin) or a Traveling Merchant like Kraft Lawrence and Holo from [Spice and Wolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spice_and_Wolf) or up and just move to another village

### Basic Features

- Randomly Generated World

  - Staring Locations:
  - Village
  - Empty (have to find a Village)
- Crafting

  - Tools
  - Appliances
  - Furniture
- Combat
- Registered Jobs

  - Guard (Defend Village)
  - Farmer (Make Crops for Village)
  - Miner (Start/Work in a Mine collecting materials)
- Having a house to store all the crap you end up hording

### Extended

- More jobs

  - Shopkeeper/Smith (make items to sell)
  - Traveling Merchant (along with horse, cart and <strike>fox eared wolf god</strike> traveling companion)
  - Mayor (make you own town)
  - Teacher
  - - Normal
  - - Dojo Master
  - - Magus (Research and teach magic to others)
  - Ronin (more or less a sell sword)
  - Bandit (like a Ronin but you get to raid people)
  - Pirate (Bandit but with a cool eyepatch and a kickin ship)
- Hunger/Thirst/Sleep Levels
- Reputation

  - low rep can get you attacked by guards or thrown in jail
  - high rep can earn you discounts and favours
- Town relations

  - Town Guard can launch attacks against enemy towns
  - trading items gotten from one town to another which they don't like can lower your rep as a merchant
- Town Law and Order

  - Lawful Towns people wont have to worry about theft.
  - the opposite end is [Tortuga](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUfY7.png) for pirates/bandits to sell their wares
- Different kinds of houses to buy
- ability to build your own house (either outside town limits or buy a plot of land in town)

  - ships will have a generic base but can be built on as if they are moving land
- NPC relationships

  - makes friend to earn favors/gain influence/get discounts/info
  - for pirates and bandits you can infiltrate a town, get info on guard placements or influence your new "friends" to help weaken a town from within
  - dating/marriages/children (same sex relationships included)
- Quests
- Bosses
- Different Town Cultures (can limit jobs/traceable items)
- Add iconic towns like [Konohagakure](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Konohagakure) or [Ba Sign Se](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Ba_Sing_Se) and add jobs associated with them such as Ninja, [Ramen Delivery Guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRC_iNWt7kM), Dai Li Agent or <strike>Dragon of the West</strike> Tea Shop Guy

Comment: Sounds [familiar](http://myanimelist.net/anime/11757/Sword_Art_Online)...

Comment: [mabinogi](http://mabinogi.nexon.net/landing/) too

Comment: complex version [Log Horizon](http://myanimelist.net/anime/17265/Log_Horizon)

Answer (score 4):

### 2D Tower Defense

Like [Orcs Must Die](http://store.steampowered.com/app/102600/) or [Dungeon Defenders](http://store.steampowered.com/app/65800/).

Basic game:

- On a pre-made level enemies follow a path to the "End". If just one enemy reaches the end, you lose.
- Enemies are generated in small batches. Let's say 1 every second for a batch of 5, with a delay of 20 seconds between batches.
- Enemies can be killed by traps that automatically trigger when enemies step on them, and need 10 seconds to reset. Trap can kill all enemies within its trigger zone.
- Player can install a limited number of traps throughout the level. Inefficient placement will result in enemies passing through them.
- Player can kill all enemies within some range from the cursor, with a significant delay. We'll figure out the game balance in the process.

Extended game:

- More levels with multiple paths, possibly randomly generated from pre-made chunks;
- Enemy types resistant to certain attack types (like ice and fire);
- Trap types more efficient and useless against various enemy types;
- Different player attacks;
- Better art and sound? eh

If you're interested in this idea, or you want to propose changes, comment below.

Comment: Just a little suggestion from my side, we can add fast forward function. It might be useful for those who have less time to complete.

Comment: I think this idea has the best prospect of completion at this point. If the team meshes and the game turns out well, there's nothing keeping the team from moving on to a different game with the experience in creating this one.

Answer (score 4):

## TCG (Trading Card Game)

examples: [Yu-Gi-Oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_Trading_Card_Game), [Weiß Schwarz](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/5825/1587), ***[Tanto Cuore](http://www.tantocuore.com/about.htm)***

### Basic Game:

- 1 VS 1 with a Computer Opponent
- 1 VS 1 with Human Opponent
- 1st Series of cards
- In-game slideshow explaining rules

### Extended Game

- 2 VS 2 Tag Team
- More Series of cards
- Playable Tutorial
- Single Player Story Mode(s)

  - Unlocking of more AI Opponents with themed decks/strategies
  - A new Story Mode for every released series
  - Tutorial can be integrated into story

### Notes

- Card Game rules will need to be discussed (personally i liked Yu-Gi-Oh's approach)
- New cards can be added later by players in a similar way to how League of Legends for Forum RPGs allows players to make new Characters

Comment: I would limit the basic game to pvp as making an AI can bog a team down. Also, rather than a tutorial, a quick video demo is probably better, as tutorials have to be pretty well thought out to be effective. once v1 is done there's nothing keeping the team from working on an AI.

Answer (score 1):

## Trajectory shooting game

example: [DDtank](http://gamewise.co/games/49267/DDTank)

## Introduction

It might be difficult but its my suggestion because I love these types of games. Trajectory shooting game will be like every person will have their own weapon and that player will use that weapon to throw it in the air and kill his opponent by correct amount of strength. Since it will be trajectory motion therefore player can adjust their angle and then throw object to hit their target. Also this game might be calculative one because users have to first calculate the correct amount of power and angle to throw object so that it will hit the target.

## Basic game:

- Human vs Computer. Like both players having health and both of them trying to kill each other by throwing objects.
- And Human vs Human matches.
- Wind system like due to wind the trajectory motion gets disturbed which will make every round different and difficult.
- There can be tutorial at starting showing how to play the game and how to improve their skills. It is important for players to learn how to play this game and how to calculate so that they can hit target.

## Extended Game

- We can use team vs team game match where every team got one chance to attack.
- It can be boss level fight. Boss level fight means player have to complete each level to earn level or any item etc.
- There can be armory settings like to increase defense and many more.
- Restricting the angle for different weapons.
- There can be different maps for various matches.

Comment: sounds like [gunbound](http://gunbound.softnyx.net/). I would limit the basic game to pvp as making an AI can bog a team down. Also, rather than a tutorial, a quick video demo is probably better, as tutorials have to be pretty well thought out to be effective. If you stick with PVP then a wind system is not needed for version 1.

Answer (score 1):

## Murder Game - FPS

this idea was inspired by one Dark Brotherhood quest in The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion. all players are inside a single house and one of them is the murderer who has to pick off the remaining players without being caught.

the murderer is chosen at random and only the murderer will know at first. the other plays win if the catch the murderer. the Murderer will then have # minutes to commit their first kill before the game restarts and a new murder is select

in order to catch the murderer the suspect has to be detained by tying them up and placed in a zone for a certain amount of time until the suspect is taken out of the game.

once the suspect has been removed from the game all players will see what the suspect saw during the time of each murder as such it will be clear what involvement, if any, the suspect had with any murders. the suspect can be freed before they are removed from the game either by other player or themselves (by having a crafted tool to help their own escape)

the game will be in the First Person so that players can see someone approaching from behind unless in front of a mirror and hopefully sound will be close to how it works in real life so that when players "sleep" they see a black screen (or some other animation as if dreaming) but they can still hear (so they can wake up if they hear a strange noise like someone sneaking about)

### Basic Game

- Single Map (Mansion Interiour)
- Multi-Player Only
- Needs (Like Hunger, Sleep, Toilet etc, like in The Sims)

  - this allows the murderer to drug/poison their victims food or try and kill during their sleep
  - if someone is expect to go take a bath the murderer can rig something up to kill them (ie. plugged in toast falls in)
- Possible list of everyday tasks that players have to do one item on the list every # minutes

  - this prevents players just staying in one room
  - this forces the murderer to blend in aswell

### Extended Game

- Other Maps

  - Estate (includes Interiors and Exterior)
  - Hotel
  - Neighborhood (remember the Pint Size Slasher from Fallout 3?)
- Other game modes

  - Hitman - the target is marked and everyone chooses roles. one player is randomly chosen as the Hitman to kill the target.
  - Death Note (Yes, a use for all those dam [Death Note Puzzle Questions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2608/1587)) - using the rules of the Death Note Kira goes to try and kill the players while they must find out who is Kira. may have to tweak the Death Note to prevent mass suicides and add a cool down time

Answer (score 0):

## Side Scrolling Shooter

Best Example: [Gunstar Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunstar_Heroes) [Sega Genesis]

with a remake for the [Game Boy Advance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunstar_Super_Heroes), and remastered to the [Wii Virtual Console](http://www.ign.com/games/gunstar-heroes/wii-864246), and [Nintendo 3DS](http://www.nintendolife.com/reviews/3ds-eshop/3d_gunstar_heroes)

This game is comprised with a game character typically from a variety of 2-3 characters to choose from. The controls are simple D-Pad with its up,down,left right, a shoot button, a jump button, and a change weapon button.

The Mechanics of the game is simple much like a survial shooter game where you shoot your way to the end of the Level, There are some little hindraces like a mini Boss or a certain task to complete before moving on to the next part of the Stage. The player selects a weapon type (i.e. laser, rifle, bazooka.. etc.)

This could be lengthy to finish with its different Stages just like in Gunstar Heroes that has 4 initial stages to chose from before going to Space aboard a spaceship (Spaceship is side scroller too). So the Initial game would probably have at least 4-5 short levels.

It would be much fun if the Player could join his/her weapons and combine it to form another weapon for more firepower. or a combination of the elements

(i.e.
fire and fire = lightning

earth and earth = metal

earth and fire = lava

just like avatar LOL haha

## Basic Game:

- Single Player (Player Chooses from 2 characters to play)
- The controls : D-Pad with its up,down,left right, a shoot button, a jump button, and a change weapon button.
- Customization is minimal. (i.e. only Weapons can be changed)
- The target is to get the the end of the level to Accomplish it and beating a Boss  at the end.
- Short Levels consisting of hordes of enemies to shoot, punch, kick etc.
- Life is in Hit Points so several hits for the player's Death
- Real time Tactics to survive the enemy hordes appearing to stop the player from moving onto the next stage
- Final Boss awaits the Last Level

## Extended Game:

- Two player / Multi-Player / Co-op Mode - Teamplay and Real time tactics combined to finish the Stage
- In Story Mode, Another player's Death can cause the partners Life to be halved for faster respawn and not to spoil the pacing of the gameplay.
- Survival Mode (how long can a player last with just a single health bar)
- Two player PVP (Last Stand- players try to shoot each other in a level with diferent platforms for real time Tactics)

Note:

This game is Best for killing time and if a multi player mode / two player mode is made, It's fun to play family or with a friend.

- Rules such as Death and Continue Game should be discussed
- comments suggestions and others are welcome for further updates
- Stages Weapons, and Bosses that will be placed should be though out first.