# Anime.SE is turning 10 this Fall. We'd like to spotlight our community for getting us here

Tags: discussion

It's been a long road, getting from though beta to here. It's been a long time, through the good and the bad. Our time is finally here. It's been 10 years.

Let's take a look back at all we've been through and share it with the rest of the SE community in celebration. In the month of November, Stack Exchange will be doing a blog celebrating communities that have made it this far, like they did in [the spring](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/27/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-ten-years-old-in-spring-2022/).

We'd like to ask the community for things they'd like mentioned or shared. It can be anything from your favorite questions/answers, post/tags, personal stories or anecdotes (good or bad) related to the site and community. It's nothing much but we'd like to share a bit of the community in our celebration banner, as it's what we'd consider the best and most important part of our site.

The content will be like a blog blurb about the community. The banners for the celebration will be live for the month of November, feel free to leave your comments or stories as answers and we'll do what we can to weave it into a narrative to share as part of our celebration banner. Feel free to leave any bits you want here. We'll try to take as much as we can. The deadline for us submitting things is October 20th to the SE Community. We'd appreciate if you can get anything to by the 18th so we can come up with something.

The winds blowing through landscape of anime and manga and it's subculture has changed significantly through these years. Through effort and perseverance we've made it to where we are. There's not much that will hold us back anymore. I got faith in the community. Don't let anything hold us back.

Anyways, did you know there is a new Bunny Girl Senpai anime coming soon? [More details](https://twitter.com/aobuta_anime/status/1573643420689584129?s=20&t=6E9-DxpTGK2Cr6VQ0AjgrA) to be revealed soon.

Another fun fact, FSN Archer's VA is the [voice](https://twitter.com/MY_MURMUR/status/1573933154074652672?cxt=HHwWgMCjzar33dcrAAAA) of a certain cute puff ball in a quite enjoyable [summer anime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikXv37oTjm0) this year that you may have missed.

Hope to hear from you all soon.

Comment: お誕生日おめでとう、みんな様！

Answer (score 13):

Alright, to get the ball rolling~

It's been a long time, I didn't even realize I have been a member for 9 years on this community! However, I only started contributing a few months later with this answer: [What is Abe's first name?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9773/what-is-abes-first-name/10014#10014), so make it 8 years, I guess?

Even though anime & manga are usually viewed as "for children", this community has proven otherwise, that anime & manga are also a serious business™:

- Let's start the journey with [What is the first ever produced anime and manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/what-is-the-first-ever-produced-anime-and-manga)
- Of course, we are also curious [Why do anime/manga characters have big eyes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/why-do-anime-manga-characters-have-big-eyes) and [Why do many characters tend to have crazy hair colors and styles?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/why-do-many-characters-tend-to-have-crazy-hair-colors-and-styles)
- We even take physics problems: [How is Misaka's railgun so destructive?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2235/how-is-misakas-railgun-so-destructive)
- And not to forget, we also appreciate *arts*: [About the artworks used in the Elfen Lied opening scenes (contains nudity)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/15130/about-the-artworks-used-in-the-elfen-lied-opening-scenes-contains-nudity)
- For intermezzo, how about something light and fun, like [Has the "It's over 9000!" meme spread back to Japan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/752/has-the-its-over-9000-meme-spread-back-to-japan) and [How much broadcast time did it take for Planet Namek to blow up?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3701/how-much-broadcast-time-did-it-take-for-planet-namek-to-blow-up)
- Next, while we also care about parental guidance on [How can I identify child-appropriate manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21936/how-can-i-identify-child-appropriate-manga) or [How to explain to my 10 year old niece that Puella Magi Madoka Magica is not a kids show?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/39633/how-to-explain-to-my-10-year-old-niece-that-puella-magi-madoka-magica-is-not-a-k)
- We also cater to older audiences, like [Why does anime usually air at night in Japan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4013/why-does-anime-usually-air-at-night-in-japan) or [What is the difference between yuri and shoujo-ai, yaoi and shounen-ai and ecchi and hentai anime genre?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2681/what-is-the-difference-between-yuri-and-shoujo-ai-yaoi-and-shounen-ai-and-ecchi)
- Finally, take a look at [What databases and listing sites exist for anime, manga, etc?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/what-databases-and-listing-sites-exist-for-anime-manga-etc) and [Are there any anime suggestion engines?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7337/are-there-any-anime-suggestion-engines) if you're interested in exploring more!

Comment: Not to mention serious ["cultured"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=hentai) posts _wink, wink_

Comment: "Even though anime & manga are usually viewed as "for children" [..] anime & manga are also a serious business" - This hits home. My wife doesn't ( won't :( ) watch anime, and it took a lot of convincing that anime is *very* different than Saturday morning cartoons

Answer (score 8):

[death-note](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-note), for those who don't know, is an anime with a Hard Magic System in the form of the titular item, a note book which causes people's deaths when their names are written in it, however it's not as simple as writing a name in as there is a series of rules which dictate who can die and how they will die.

Because of this people want to know the limits which you can take these rules and this spawned the the Anime and Manga SE meme [Death Note Puzzles](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2608/1587)

We've had

- Extending life with the Death Note

  - [Can I increase my lifespan by killing myself using the Death Note?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/907/can-i-increase-my-lifespan-by-killing-myself-using-the-death-note)
  - [Old age as cause of death?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11515/death-note-old-age-as-cause-of-death)
- The limit to it's ability to control people

  - [How far can you manipulate someone with a Death Note?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21659/how-far-can-you-manipulate-someone-with-a-death-note)
  - [Can the Death Note manipulate people whose names aren't written in it?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/32437/can-the-death-note-manipulate-people-whose-names-arent-written-in-it)
- Possible immunity to the Death Note

  - [Is a person who wasn't named by his/her parents immune to the Death Note?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21270/is-a-person-who-wasnt-named-by-his-her-parents-immune-to-the-death-note)
  - [Does writing an alias in the Death Note count as misspelling the name?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/27564/does-writing-an-alias-in-the-death-note-count-as-misspelling-the-name)

but not all the rules were about using the Death Note. some were rules on Shinigami Interaction, one such rule lead to asking the question on [how far you could take a sexual relationship with a Shinigami](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/42218/in-death-note-how-far-could-sexual-interaction-go-with-a-shinigami-before-it)